# Filter Array PFObjects with another Array

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I have two arrays of [PFObjects]. I am trying to filter array2 `restaurantPFObjects` based on the objectIDs of array1 `foodPhotoObjectsRestaurantID`. However `self.detailsForFoodPhotos.append(item)` never gets called.

Current Code:

```
    var foodPhotoObjectsRestaurantID: [PFObject] = self.foodPhotoObjects.map { $0.objectForKey("RestaurantName") as PFObject }

    for var index = 0 ; index <= foodPhotoObjectsRestaurantID.count - 1 ; index += 1 {

        //self.detailsForFoodPhotos = self.restaurantPFObjects!.filter({$0 == foodPhotoObjectsRestaurantID[index]})
        for item in self.restaurantPFObjects! {
            if (item == foodPhotoObjectsRestaurantID[index]){
                self.detailsForFoodPhotos.append(item)
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Array1: foodPhotoObjectsRestaurantID

```
    [<Restaurant: 0x17411ef90, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    }, <Restaurant: 0x17411f0b0, objectId: lZJJHkFmQl, localId: (null)> {
    }, <Restaurant: 0x17411f1d0, objectId: lZJJHkFmQl, localId: (null)> {
    }, <Restaurant: 0x17411f2f0, objectId: lZJJHkFmQl, localId: (null)> {
    }, <Restaurant: 0x17411f410, objectId: lZJJHkFmQl, localId: (null)> {
    }, <Restaurant: 0x17411f530, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    }]
```

#### Array2: restaurantPFObjects

```
[<Restaurant: 0x17411a940, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    Atmosphere = 609;
    City = "New York";
    CloseHours =     (
        0015,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350
    );
    Closed = 0;
    Country = "United States";
    FairPrice = 209;
    FoodQuality = 900;
    FoodType = Japanese;
    Name = "Le Bec Fin";
    OpenHours =     (
        0011,
        0015,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011
    );
    OverallDislikes = 250;
    OverallLikes = 1000;
    Phone = "516-507-0982";
    Photo = "<PFFile: 0x174465380>";
    Price = 1;
    Rating = 1;
    RestaurantLoc = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x1742342e0, latitude: 40.759210, longitude: -73.984631>";
    RestaurantType = Lunch;
    Service = 803;
    SiteLink = "http://www.google.com";
    State = NY;
    Street = "900 main st.";
    Zipcode = 10055;
}, <Restaurant: 0x17411ce60, objectId: lZJJHkFmQl, localId: (null)> {
    Atmosphere = 100;
    City = "New York";
    CloseHours =     (
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350,
        2350
    );
    Closed = 0;
    Country = "United States";
    FairPrice = 500;
    FoodQuality = 350;
    FoodType = "Japanese, Chinese";
    Name = "Sumo Japan";
    OpenHours =     (
        1215,
        0015,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011
    );
    OverallDislikes = 400;
    OverallLikes = 500;
    Phone = "888-888-8888";
    Photo = "<PFFile: 0x174465500>";
    Price = 0;
    Rating = 5;
    RestaurantLoc = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x174234420, latitude: 40.759220, longitude: -73.984632>";
    RestaurantType = Breakfast;
    Service = 200;
    SiteLink = "http://www.google.com";
    State = NY;
    Street = "1 main st.";
    Zipcode = 10055;
}, <Restaurant: 0x17411cdd0, objectId: LA74J92QDA, localId: (null)> {
    Atmosphere = 9;
    City = "New York";
    CloseHours =     (
        0015,
        0015,
        0015,
        0015,
        0015,
        0015,
        0015
    );
    Closed = 1;
    Country = "United States";
    FairPrice = 10;
    FoodQuality = 10;
    FoodType = Japanese;
    Name = "Honey Pig";
    OpenHours =     (
        0011,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011,
        0011
    );
    OverallDislikes = 0;
    OverallLikes = 10;
    Phone = "888-888-8888";
    Photo = "<PFFile: 0x174465440>";
    Price = 2;
    Rating = 3;
    RestaurantLoc = "<PFGeoPoint: 0x174234380, latitude: 40.759212, longitude: -73.984632>";
    RestaurantType = Dinner;
    Service = 9;
    SiteLink = "http://www.google.com";
    State = NY;
    Street = "1 main st.";
    Zipcode = 10055;
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the equality operator where you should be using an equality method. This is probably comparing object pointers, which is not what you want:

```
item == foodPhotoObjectsRestaurantID[index]
```

You should be doing something like this:

```
item.objectId == foodPhotoObjectsRestaurantID[index].objectId
```

Comment: Both are PFObjects. The comparison should be valid

Comment: Take a look at the arrays. The PFObjects are not the same pointers, even if the objectIds are the same. Thus you can't compare pointers, you have to compare objectIds.

Comment: `String does not have member named isEqualToString` Should i convert the entire array into anyobject?

Comment: Life saver. But yes I understand what you mean when you say the objectIds are different. Thanks for the help

Comment: The objectIds may be the same, but the objects themselves live in different places in memory, and therefore their pointers are not the same. object1 == object2 compares pointers. object1.objectId == object2.objectId does what you want. :-)

Comment: @Emma you can customize the equality infix operator in Swift to test for objectIds automatically when comparing two PFObjects. See "Equivalence Operators" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_43

Comment: @huhitschris interesting, im going to give this a try and post back if I end up using it. Thanks!